# Getting internet Access to Ec2 instance in a public subnet without having a public IPv4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, ipv4

I have some instances which is already having public Ipv4 address and i have manually remove that. Actually the instances need access while patch and updates. I have removed the Public Ipv4 address from those instances.
I think i cannot use a NAT gateway or creating a NA instance, because in docs i have read its for the instances in private subnet to get the internet access. Also if i change the route table, all the resources in that subnet get affected. I only need the internet access without Ipv4 in some instances in that subnet. Unfortunately my VPC and instances are legacy and so IPv6 is also seems not possible.

Please share if any solutions available.

Comment: If IPv6 is not possible, then NAT is your only option